# Objects.hash(Object... values): How are hashes of values cambined?

Tags: java, hash

How are the hashes of arguments combined when calculating `Objects.hash(Object... values)`?

Here is the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...)) which says it´s equivalent to `Arrays.hashCode(Object[])`. That opens up the question: how exactly does the latter calculate the hash?

Comment: I assume you have read the code for this method.... so what are you asking?

Comment: Why don't you keep drilling [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode-java.lang.Object:A-) and [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--)?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#3637

Comment: @PeterLawrey the algo is actually specified in the javadoc (of List).

Comment: I assume he is not understanding the [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Comment: @assylias True, I stopped at the source, but the Javadoc means it won't ever be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is answered in the documentation for int hashCode() in List. (suggested by assylias).

```
  int hashCode = 1;
  for (E e : list)
      hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
```

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, `Objects.hash(Object...)` is equivalent to `Arrays.hashCode`. That method, in turn, says that it's [equivalent to `Arrays.asList(arr).hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode-java.lang.Object:A-). The List interface [defines a contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--) for hashCode, which is that it must be equivalent to:

```
 int hashCode = 1;
 for (E e : list)
     hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
```